# Eclipse Formatter: Line wrapping for method names not working?

Tags: eclipse, formatter

where I work we are using the same code style for eclipse in the team and in addition we have SonarQube running to find style errors (and more).
We've noticed a problem with our max. line length, which is set to 140 characters:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaqVy.png

Eclipse won't wrap our methods and constructors and we have several that are more than 140 characters long. It's just a beauty issue, but I it would be nice to get rid of hundreds of issues in SonarQube.

I've googled for the error and found several bug entries at https://bugs.eclipse.org, but most of them are very old.
Does anyone have a workaround or solution for this?

Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0)
Ubuntu 14.04

edit:
Ok, I did some testing. It looks like the line length is a problem, when the opening bracket is the only char beyond 140 characters. So if the closing bracket for the parameters is the 139th char and the opening bracket for the method the 141 char, then it won't wrap the line.

Comment: did you set eclipse to format source code in the `save actions` page? method declaration longer than 140 columns is (imho) bad; or, you could eventually lower the priority of the sonar related rule

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: Yes, we have a save action, but also manually calling the formatter won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and an easy workaround:

Eclipse ignores the line wrap, if the only char higher than the maximum is the opening brace "{". So the easiest solution for us, as we don't want to update our profile: We just increased the line length rule in SonarQube to 143.

Answer (score 1):

This is on windows. But I guess eclipse should have similar options on linux.
Eclipse->Window->Preference->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Line wrapping.

You can also create profile in Formatter with specific setting for everything and share with your team.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? Once you configure this setting, you can go to package explorer, right click on project, and  invoke source->format option. This will format and change line width of all existing source files in project. You don't need to manually format each file.

Comment: It doesn't work. My screenshot shows the settings for the method declaration with parameters. The same setting is set for constructors. Neither the safe action nor Source -> Format wraps the line. The same for 6 colleagues  who are using the same profile.